# Android testOnly attribute in Manifest

Tags: android

While trying to install my application using `adb install` I got an error saying:  `Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_TEST_ONLY: installPackageLI]` after checking what it means, I found out that my merged `Manifest` contains an attribute: `android:testOnly="true"`, however the actual `Manifest` **does not** contains this attribute. So my question it could have been set in the merged version?

Comment: https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/10/31/android-studio-3p0-flag-test-only.html

Comment: @CommonsWare thank you. I want to point out that is something new that started happening since I changed `targetSdk` to 31. It never happened to me when it was `tagetSdk:30`. Moreover, I use the latest version of` Android Studio` so it seems odd that is started to happening just now.